# What to use for CSS utility classes (padding/margin...) with Clarity.Design

Tags: css, vmware-clarity

I'm using VMware Clarity, but I notice there are no utility classes like [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) has to apply padding, margin, round images, etc.

Do I need to implement this myself or is there a complementary library I can use?

I'm using the CSS version without [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)).

Comment: You can use -- http://tachyons.io/#style or http://buildwithbeard.com/

Comment: @SumitPatel Thanks, yes that's just what I needed, nothing fancy great!

Comment: Let me add that in answer thanks.

Comment: We don't provide such classes in Clarity, we recommend you to create your own or find one that you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below two options.

- [Tachyons](http://tachyons.io/#style)
- [Beard](http://buildwithbeard.com/)

Answer (score 0):

VMware Clarity is build upon [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29). I suggest to use Bootstrap for utility classes. You will find lot of resemblance of VMware Clarity styling with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you need utility classes is to take a look at *[Blueprint CSS](https://blueprintcss.dev)*. It works well mixing with other CSS frameworks. (I am the creator/maintainer) :)